# Bottom of NavHostFragment hidden behind BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I have layout with a nav bar at the bottom and the main content inside a NavHostFragment. Now the bottom of the NavHostFragment is hidden behind the nav bar. How can I fix this?

This is the main layout of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And one of the fragments of the nav host:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: just use linear layout no need for ConstraintLayout in your case

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and I found a cure. @ianhanniballake was right, but that is not a final solution. The problem is in value of 'layout_height' of NavHostFragment. You should walk through next 3 steps in *activity_main.xml*:

1. Be sure or remove `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` from root ConstraintLayout
2. Add `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nav_host_fragment"` to <BottomNavigationView>
3. Change in <fragment ... NavHostFragment>

   `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

to

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

=======================

***A Little investigation:***

Let's create a 'Bottom Navigation Activity'-project from scratch.

**Step 0.1:**

add background to root of activity_main.xml

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
```

**Step 0.2:** 
change content of fragment_home.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="L_T"
        android:background="#ffcccc"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
        android:textSize="120sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="R_B"
        android:background="#ccffcc"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:textSize="120sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You will see:

[image]

**Step 1:** remove `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`:

[image]

**Step 2:** Add `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nav_host_fragment"` constraint for BottomNavigationView

[image]

**Step 3 (Final)**. change height to 0dp and add `android:layout_weight="1"` for NavHostFragment

[image]

PS.Hope this helps for other similar problems

Comment: Excellent answer. Solved my issue. I have been searching for a solution for the past two hours.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nav_host_fragment"` on your `nav_view` - you need both directions to build a constraint chain:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nav_host_fragment"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Of course, there's no reason to use `ConstraintLayout` for this case - if you have solely vertically stacked, non-overlapping views, you should use a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Now the content is fully visible but the top of it is partially hidden behind the ActionBar and the bottom of the nav bar is pushed down so that only a part of it is still visible.

Comment: Do you see the same issue if you use `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>` instead of `<fragment>`?

Comment: In that case I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity does not have a NavController set`

Comment: You should be following the solution in [the known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142847973) and getting the NavController from the NavHostFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Add

> android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"

in your `androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment`

Comment: Probably not a great idea to hard code a value like that, Google might change the height of the bottom nav one day.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_height="0dp"` for `NavHostFragment`.

When you want to adjust `width / height` based on `constraints` so that they take up remaining space in relation to a `constraint` with other `View`, set the `width / height` to `0dp`. Only then the `Constraints` work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below layout. You can change the appCustomViewPager to anything which is usable for you.

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.impelsys.ebooks.ui.AppCustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

I used `LinearLayout` as main layout and added `weights` to the child layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```